# "The file format is invalid" error message Pages Mac

Tags: pages

Got an error message opening my file that has always worked till now. Stored on iCloud Drive, so I can open it on my iPhone X too. Updated my Mac, but still not working. Not sure what to do, have tried a few things but nothing works. Cheers

[image]

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail such as your macOS (before and after) and Pages versions? How big was the file? When did this start? Have you had any problem with any other Pages file recently? Thx.

Comment: Hey thanks. Nothing has changed on my Mac. Both Software and App is the newest update

Comment: Can you open the file via your iPhone?